# What does "tbl" stand for in R (for example in dplyr package)?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the `dplyr` package they talk about `tbl`, how one can join them and so on.

I have looked everywhere for an explanation for `tbl` but can't find anything useful.

I suspect it is a term that is not just used in the `dplyr` package, but just in case I will let you know that bumped into it when working with `dplyr`.

I don't know what it means so my question is:

**What does `tbl` stand for (either in the `dplyr` package or in general)?**

Comment: I spent 10 minutes trying to find useful examples and finally found that I needed quotes around the table name for it to return the table data from database --> tbl(con,"tableName"). The documentation hasn't improved over the last few years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tbl = table

in dlplyr there are several types of tables :

join         ==>    Join two tbls together.

join.tbl_df  ==>    Join **data frame** tbls.

join.tbl_dt  ==>    Join **data table** tbls.

join.tbl_sql ==>    Join **sql** tbls.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite hard to find information on this topic. The docs for `tbl`/`is.tbl` give very little information.

To the best of my knowledge, tbl is a generic class for tabular data that dplyr functions take in as data arguments.

Creating a tbl prepents "tbl_" to the class name. From [dplyr/tbl.r](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/tbl.r):

```
#' Create a "tbl" object
#'
#' `tbl()` is the standard constructor for tbls. `as.tbl()` coerces,
#' and `is.tbl()` tests.
#'
#' @keywords internal
#' @export
#' @param subclass name of subclass. "tbl" is an abstract base class, so you
#'   must supply this value. `tbl_` is automatically prepended to the
#'   class name
#' @param object to test/coerce.
#' @param ... For `tbl()`, other fields used by class. For `as.tbl()`,
#'   other arguments passed to methods.
#' @examples
#' as.tbl(mtcars)
make_tbl <- function(subclass, ...) {
  subclass <- paste0("tbl_", subclass)
  structure(list(...), class = c(subclass, "tbl"))
```

Using any dplyr function (join, select, mutate, etc.) on a data.frame gives back a data.frame.

```
library(dplyr)
select(mtcars, cyl) %>% class
```

However, calling a dplyr function on a tbl_df/tibble (see [my answer on tibble vs tbl_df](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527549/3163618)) gives back a tbl_df/tibble.

```
> select(tbl_df(mtcars), cyl) %>% class
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Here we see `tbl_df` inherits from `tbl`, which inherits from `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a [tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tbl_df-class.html).

> The tbl_df class is a subclass of data.frame, created in order to have different default behaviour. The colloquial term "tibble" refers to a data frame that has the tbl_df class. Tibble is the central data structure for the set of packages known as the tidyverse, including dplyr, ggplot2, tidyr, and readr.