# What is the difference between as.tibble(), as_data_frame(), and tbl_df()?

Tags: r, dplyr, terminology, tidyverse, tibble

I remember reading somewhere that `as.tibble()` is an *alias* for `as_data_frame()`, but I don't know what exactly an *alias* is in programming terminology. Is it similar to a wrapper?

So I guess my question probably comes down to the difference in possible usages between `tbl_df()` and `as_data_frame()`: what are the differences between them, if any?

More specifically, given a (non-tibble) data frame `df`, I often turn it into a tibble by using:

```
df <- tbl_df(df)
```

Wouldn't

```
df <- as_data_frame(df)
```

do the same thing? If so, are there other cases where the two functions `tbl_df()` and `as_data_frame()` can not be used interchangeably to get the same result?

The [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/tbl_df) says that

> `tbl_df()` forwards the argument to `as_data_frame()`

does that mean that `tbl_df()` is a wrapper or alias for `as_data_frame()`? R documentation doesn't seem to say anything about `as.tibble()` and I forgot where I read that it was an alias for `as_data_frame()`. Also, [apparently](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.2/topics/as_tibble) `as_tibble()` is another alias for `as_data_frame()`.

If these four functions really are all the same function, what is the sense in giving one function four different names? Isn't that more confusing than helpful?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer your question of "whether it is confusing", I think so :) .

`as.tibble` and `as_tibble` are the same; both simply call the S3 method `as_tibble`:

```
> as.tibble
function (x, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("as_tibble")
}
<environment: namespace:tibble>
```

`as_data_frame` and `tbl_df` are not exactly the same; `tbl_df` calls `as_data_frame`:

```
> tbl_df
function (data) 
{
    as_data_frame(data)
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Note `tbl_df` is in `dplyr` while `as_data_frame` is in the `tibble` package:

```
> as_data_frame
function (x, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("as_data_frame")
}
<environment: namespace:tibble>
```

but of course it calls the same function, so they are "the same", or aliases as you say.

Now, we can look at the differences between the generic methods `as_tibble` and `as_data_frame`.  First, we look at the methods of each:

```
> methods(as_tibble)
[1] as_tibble.data.frame* as_tibble.default*    as_tibble.list* as_tibble.matrix*     as_tibble.NULL*      
[6] as_tibble.poly*       as_tibble.table*      as_tibble.tbl_df* as_tibble.ts*        
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
> methods(as_data_frame)
[1] as_data_frame.data.frame* as_data_frame.default*  as_data_frame.grouped_df* as_data_frame.list*      
[5] as_data_frame.matrix*     as_data_frame.NULL*       as_data_frame.table*      as_data_frame.tbl_cube*  
[9] as_data_frame.tbl_df*    
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

If you check out the [code for](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/master/R/as_tibble.R#L144) `as_tibble`, you can see that the definitions for many of the `as_data_frame` methods as well.  `as_tibble` defines two additional methods which aren't defined for `as_data_frame`, `as_tibble.ts` and `as_tibble.poly`.  I'm not really sure why they couldn't be also defined for `as_data_frame`.

`as_data_frame` has two additional methods, which are both defined in `dplyr`: `as_data_frame.tbl_cube` and `as_data_frame.grouped_df`.

`as_data_frame.tbl_cube` use the weaker checking of `as.data.frame` (yes, bear with me) to then call `as_data_frame`:

```
> getAnywhere(as_data_frame.tbl_cube)
function (x, ...) 
{
    as_data_frame(as.data.frame(x, ..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

while `as_data_frame.grouped_df` ungroups the passed dataframe.

Overall, it seems that `as_data_frame` should be seen as providing additional functionality over `as_tibble`, unless you are dealing with `ts` or `poly` objects.

Comment: Just one follow-up: how do you check the code for the functions? Aren't they written in C++, which prevents them from being viewable in R?

Comment: I used a combination of  ```functionName``` (note no parentheses), ```methods(functionName)```, ```getAnywhere(functionName.classMethodName)```, and looking directly at the ```tibble``` and ```dplyr``` source code.

Comment: Yes, they are on github.

Comment: Some of the elements of this answer are now outdated, `as_data_frame` is soft deprecated and just calls `as_tibble` (it's not a generic anymore), `tbl_df` calls  `as_tibble(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")`. `as.tibble` is soft deprecated

Comment: `as_tibble` now also throws a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [introduction to tibble](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/), it seems like tibbles supersede `tbl_df`.

> I’m pleased to announce tibble, a new package for manipulating and printing data frames in R. Tibbles are a modern reimagining of the data.frame, keeping what time has proven to be effective, and throwing out what is not. The name comes from dplyr: originally you created these objects with `tbl_df()`, which was most easily pronounced as “tibble diff”.
>
> [...]This package extracts out the tbl_df class associated functions from dplyr.

To add to the confusion, `tbl_df` now calls `as_tibble`, which is the preferred alias for `as_data_frame` and `as.tibble`: ([Hadley Wickham's comment on the issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/82#issuecomment-225607351), and [as_tibble docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.4.2/topics/as_tibble))

```
> tbl_df
function (data) 
{
    as_tibble(data, .name_repair = "check_unique")
}
```

According to the help description of `tbl_df()`, it is deprecated and `tibble::as_tibble()` should be used instead. `as_data_frame` and `as.tibble` help pages both redirect to `as_tibble`.

When calling `class` on a tibble, the class name still shows up as `tbl_df`:

```
> as_tibble(mtcars) %>% class
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```