# Why a replace function works on data frames but not on tibbles in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I've looked at the discussion [What is the difference between as.tibble(), as_data_frame(), and tbl_df()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942328/what-is-the-difference-between-as-tibble-as-data-frame-and-tbl-df) to figure out why a `replace_na` function (shown below) works on data frames but not on tibbles. Could you help me understand why it doesn't work on tibbles? How can the function be modified so it can work for both `data.frame` and `tibble`?

## Data

```
library(dplyr)

#dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), gender = c("M", "F", NA, "F"
), grade = c("A", NA, NA, NA), age = c(2, NA, 2, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), gender = c("M", "F", "M", 
"F"), grade = c("A", "A", "B", "NG"), age = c(22, 23, 21, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## replace function

```r
replace_na <- function(df_to, df_from) {
  replace(df_to, is.na(df_to), df_from[is.na(df_to)])
}
```

## Usage

`replace_na(df1,df2)`

> Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
>
> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
>
> Called from: abort(error_dim_column_index(j))

However; coercing the `arglist` to data frame produces the desired output as shown below.

```r
replace_na(as.data.frame(df1), as.data.frame(df2))
#   id gender grade age
# 1  1      M     A   2
# 2  2      F     A  23
# 3  3      M     B   2
# 4  4      F    NG  19
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is.na()` returns a logical matrix for a data frame:

```r
is.na(df1) 
#>         id gender grade   age
#> [1,] FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE   TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [4,] FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The base `data.frame` class supports subsetting with a matrix; `tbl_df` is more strict, and does not.

```r
as.data.frame(df2)[is.na(df1)]
#> [1] "M"  "A"  "B"  "NG" "23" "19"
df2[is.na(df1)]
#> Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
```

To make your `replace_na()` function work with a `tbl_df` you need to do the operation separately for each column. For example, with recursion:

```r
replace_na <- function(x, y) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    x[] <- Map(replace_na, x, y)
    return(x)
  }

  replace(x, is.na(x), y[is.na(x)])
}

replace_na(df1, df2)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id gender grade   age
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 M      A         2
#> 2     2 F      A        23
#> 3     3 M      B         2
#> 4     4 F      NG       19
```

This method is also generally faster:

```r
replace_na_vec <- function(x, y) {
  replace(x, is.na(x), y[is.na(x)])
}

df1_10k <- do.call("rbind", replicate(10000, df1, simplify = FALSE))
df2_10k <- do.call("rbind", replicate(10000, df2, simplify = FALSE))

bench::mark(
  check = FALSE,
  new = replace_na(df1, df2),
  old = replace_na_vec(as.data.frame(df1), as.data.frame(df2)),
  new_10k = replace_na(df1_10k, df2_10k),
  old_10k = replace_na_vec(as.data.frame(df1_10k), as.data.frame(df2_10k))
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 new         74.01us  97.79us   7295.          0B    12.6 
#> 2 old        269.97us 529.93us   1845.     81.02KB     8.23
#> 3 new_10k      1.82ms   2.75ms    338.      4.27MB    32.3 
#> 4 old_10k     94.29ms 104.05ms      9.68   10.24MB     2.42
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Mikko, and though not part of the question, I wonder how doing separately interplay with performance when compared with coercing the `arglist` using `as.data.frame`?

Comment: @deepseefan I added a quick benchmark: it would seem the separate-approach is generally faster than using matrix subsetting with `as.data.frame()`.